# Fatch mysql data without some data

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table here is  row name is "name" value list   "Subadmin,reseller5,reseller4,reseller3,reseller2,reseller1"

i want to query value without top data where match query value.

suppose my query is

```
$sql="select * from level_list where name!='reseller3' ORDER BY id desc"; 
$query2 = $this->db->query($sql);
foreach($query2->result() as $user_data) {
    echo $user_data->real_name."<br/>";
}
```

here is now output is"Subadmin,reseller5,reseller4,reseller2,reseller1"
but i want to output is "reseller2,reseller1"

if my query `$sql="select * from level_list where name!='reseller2' ORDER BY id desc";`
should output "reseller1" only.

How i do it?

Comment: Generally it's bad practice to select * , select the columns you need instead.

Comment: _"`$sql="select * from level_list where name!='reseller2' ORDER BY id desc";` should output "reseller1" only."_ - Why? That query says "select records where `name` is not equal to `reseller2`". That will give you _all_ names except just that specific one.

Comment: `Subadmin,reseller5,reseller4,reseller2,reseller1` are columns or values? If you only want `reseller1` why say `name!='reseller2'`, just write `name ='reseller1'`.